# Socket programming receiving TCP data from a software on a different system using python

Tags: python, sockets, tcpclient

I am trying to use a software on computer A which sends TCP data blocks to computer B. My client program is on computer B written in python to receive the data blocks. But when I run my code, I get the following error.

```
OSError: [WinError 10065] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host
```

The following is my client.py

```
def Main():
    host = '146.254.8.132' #IP Address of the system which has the software sending TCP data
    port = 5003 #TCP port number used by the software
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host,port))

    i = 0
    #for i < 2:
    len_message = s.recv(3)
    print(len_message)
    while len_message:
        bytes_length = int(len_message.decode())
        #data_length = (bytes_length + 3)
        print(bytes_length)
        #print(data_length)
        data = s.recv(bytes_length)
        print(data)
        write_file(data)
        len_message = s.recv(3)
    #i+=1
    s.close()

def write_file(data):
        with open("Output.txt", "wb") as text_file:
            text_file.write(data)
            text_file.write('\n'.encode())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Why am I getting that error and not able to receive the data? 
Could it be possible because my client is not connected to any network but my server is on the system which has an ethernet connection? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you make sure that firewall rules have allowed the incoming port or ip address?

Comment: How do you do that? Sorry, I am not aware about this.

Comment: I entered the port as 2055 for TCP under Inbound rules but doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Can you try to connect to www.google.com at 443 port and see if the connection happen? Your problem look like default high port blocking on windows

Comment: Could it be possible that I am having this issue because my client is not on any network but the server is connected to the ethernet? Should they both be connected to the same network?